# Handlebars - rendering server and client side with same template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have the following handlebars template that needs to be used in two ways. The first is with rendering initial server side content on page load. The second is to render additional content to the page when the user clicks a CTA to fetch more content.

After following some tutorials online for using handlebars with AJAX I wrapped my template with a `<script>` tag that had a type of `text/x-handlebars-template`. Here is the template:

```
<script id="my-unique-id" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="element">
        \{{name}}
    </div>
</script>
```

The issue here is that I need to escape the curly braces with a `\` in order to use my template within a `<script>` tag. This template works fine with ajax requests. Here is an example request where I would use the script ID to render out content returned from an API:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  data: data,
  url: url, 
  success: function(response) {
    var Handlebars = window.Handlebars;
    var templateId = '#my-unique-id';
    for(var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {

      var template = Handlebars.compile($(templateId).html());   

      $('.some-parent-container').append('<div>' + template(response.Articles[i]) + '</div>');
    }
  }
});
```

BUT when I try and render the same template on the server it does not render out because it is within a script tag, I also believe that using the `\` to escape the curly brackets in the template only works client side and not server side.

Could anyone suggest the correct approach for having a template that could render out both on client and server side without having to duplicate the template file?